# Converting string to float with Python 3.2

Tags: python

The purpose of this program is to display the sum, average, max, and min of use based input.

```
count=0.0
Sum=0.0
average=0.0
data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:"))
Min=data
Max=data

while data!="":
    count+=1
    number=float(data)
    Sum+=number
    average=Sum/count

    if data<Min:
        Min=data
    if data>Max:
        Max=data
    data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:"))

print(count,("numbers entered."))
print("Sum:",Sum)
print("Average:",average)
print("Min:",Min)
print("Max:",Max)
```

The problem is with line 20:
data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:"))

When i press ENTER to end the loop it says that it was unable to convert string to float and errors. What am I doing wrong ?????

Comment: The result of hitting <ENTER> at the prompt is being passed to `float()`, which cannot convert an empty string.  Change that line to `data=input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:")`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you shouldn't convert to `float` immediately. Also, this is not how you do `do..while` loop in Python.

```
while True:
    data = input('Enter a number or ENTER to quit: ')
    if not data: break

    data = float(data)
    # ...
```

This way you don't have to duplicate code, or to prolong the life of `data` name unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't see any problem with actually using the condition of the `while` loop? Why use `True` and then a manual `break`?

Comment: @agf: That's the idiomatic `do...while` in Python. With `while cond:` you've got code duplication (see e.g. the OP snippet).

Comment: @agf:  Presumably to avoid duplicating the prompt before the `while` loop.

Comment: If you try this, you will find that it still errors out. The `input()` call actually raises the exception.

Comment: @Chriszuma: No, this is Python 3, not Python 2. `input` in 3 is equivalent to `raw_input` in 2.

Comment: I'd argue than an extra `data = input(prompt)` before the loop with a `while data:` is clearer and more Pythonic than `while True:` with an `if not data: break`. Another possible solution: just set `data` to `True` before the loop.

Comment: @agf: You can argue, but this is how most people implement do-while loops. The condition is still part of the loop, and no code is duplicated. Other solutions are more or less unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the data type of `input` is **string**. Pressing ENTER will return an empty string which cannot be casted into a float, since the string is empty and there is nothing to be casted, which is generating the error. Here are two solutions to handle this error.

### Solution 1

Do not cast input into float directly, but cast it when assigning the value of input to any variable.

```
data=input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:")
```

Add the following statement before the loop to handle the condition when the user wants to exit without entering any number.

```
if not data: # If user wants to exit without entering any number
    Max = 0
    Min = 0
else:  # Cast the inputs by user to float
    Max = float(data)
    Min = float(data)
```

Lastly add the following line at the beginning inside the loop.

```
data = float(data)
```

**Complete Code**

```
count=0.0
Sum=0.0
average=0.0
data=input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:")
if not data:
    Max = 0
    Min = 0
else:
    Max = float(data)
    Min = float(data)

while data!='':
    data = float(data)
    count+=1 
    number=float(data)
    Sum+=number
    average=Sum/count

    if data<Min:
        Min=data
    if data>Max:
        Max=data
    data=input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:")

print(count,("numbers entered."))
print("Sum:",Sum)
print("Average:",average)
print("Min:",Min)
print("Max:",Max)
```

### Solution 2

What you can also do is set a default value for empty inputs. Here since you are casting input into a float, you can set any number as the default value for empty inputs. **However, I will not prefer this because if the user enters the same number as the default value, the loop will be terminated.** In the following example I've only modified two lines of your code and set the default value for empty inputs as 0.

```
count=0.0
Sum=0.0
average=0.0
data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:") or 0)
Min=data
Max=data

while data!=0:
    count+=1
    number=float(data)
    Sum+=number
    average=Sum/count

    if data<Min:
        Min=data
    if data>Max:
        Max=data
    data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:") or 0)

print(count,("numbers entered."))
print("Sum:",Sum)
print("Average:",average)
print("Min:",Min)
print("Max:",Max)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `float()` function raises an exception for blank inputs. You must catch this exception for your loop to work as intended. Here is the simplest fix:

*In Python 2.x, it is actually the `input()` call that raises the exception, not `float()`. So, if you are using Python 2.x, my solution is the only one here that works.*

```
while True:
    count+=1
    Sum+=data
    average=Sum/count

    if data<Min:
        Min=data
    if data>Max:
        Max=data
    try:
      data=float(input("Enter a number or just ENTER to quit:"))
    except:
      break
```

Comment: Look at `number=float(data)`. The `float` on `input` is completely unnecessary and so the `try` / `except` (__not__ `catch`) is unnecessary too.

Comment: Notice that there are two conversions to float in his code.  He only needs the one at the top of the `while` loop.

Comment: @Chriszuma:  bzzt!  You cannot do assignment in an expression.

Comment: The correct solution on Python 2 isn't to use `try`/ `except` but to use `raw_input`.

Comment: @agf yes, that is a better solution. Notice my choice of wording "simplest" - meaning least modification to the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are incorrect, because `sum, min`, and `max` are all functions. Change them to different names such as  *"datasum", "datamin", and "datamax"*, so that the program does not confuse them with the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Python by default takes input in the string format only. Don't do direct type casting in python like string to float. It will give an error immediately.
The best way to conversion of type string to float is::

```
string_data = input("enter the data")
enter the data 123
string_data '123'
float_data = float(string_data)
float_data 123.0
```